# Spring hibernate behaviour with multiple threads

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate

I have a requirement wherein a lot of database operations are required. Basically it is a bulk upload which supports 100 000 data operations. I divide the file in chunks and supply that to multiple threads. What i want to achieve is that db operation should be successful only if all threads succeed else it should rollback entire operation.

I have read a lot of stuff where people insist not to use spring hibernate with multiple threads. Is this possible using spring SessionFactory and if yes what are important stuff that needs to be kept in mind.

Comment: You should go for StatelessSession instead of SessionFactory if you want to save non batched data, the main reason it is StatelessSession will not overload your memory, you must understand how Hibernate works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to solve this. Sharing code snippet that might help others

This can be achieved by keeping transaction at thread level. However u would require a shared object between all those threads. This shared object will keep a track of status of all this threads and notify them if either fails. If failure notification is recieved by this threads they themselves can throw an exception and their transaction will be rollbacked.

Example code Code in individual threads

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void saveData(Product product, ProductStatusObject productStatusObject) throws Exception {
    productDao.persist(product);
    if(product.getId() == 5) {
        productStatusObject.updateCounter(false);
    } else {
        productStatusObject.updateCounter(true);
    }
    if(!productStatusObject.getStatus()) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Code in shared class

```
private final int totalThreads;

private int executedThreads = 0;
private Boolean finalStatus = true;

public ProductStatusObject(int totalThreads) {
    this.totalThreads = totalThreads;
}

public synchronized void updateCounter(Boolean threadStatus) throws InterruptedException {
    executedThreads ++;
    if(!threadStatus) {
        this.finalStatus = false;
    }
    if(totalThreads == executedThreads) {
        notifyAll();
    } else {
        wait();
    }

}

public synchronized Boolean getStatus() {
    return finalStatus;
}
```

Here the failure condition is if any of thread is saving data with id 5 all threads will rollback their code. Else all will succeed